# Fast way to check if array of dictionaries contain a dictionary with key?

Tags: objective-c

I have array of `NSDictionaries` , in which i have to check if a dictionary with a certain key is exist, and it should be as fast as possible (done many times in real time )

To check if dic has key you have :

```
BOOL contains = [[dictionary allKeys] containsObject:obj];
```

or   `if([ dic objecetForKey:@"key"] != nil )`

but to check the full array i have to run on *all its objects* ?

e.g

```
bool is=0;
for(nsdictionary *dic in array)
if([ dic objecetForKey:@"key"] != nil )
is=1;

//is says if i have the dic .
```

Comment: yes, for an array you have to touch every object TILL you find a match

Comment: Without changing your storage setup, yes, you will have to check each item individually. Depending on your situation, it may be beneficial to have a "global" map, which links keys to dictionaries within your array, or something similar. Then you can reduce this operation significantly at the cost of increasing memory usage and time-to-insert.

Comment: There is no magic.  Unless you create some other directory to search, you have to examine each entry.  You might be able to use KVC or a "predicate", but it wouldn't be any faster (probably slower).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is good, but I would insert a break statement, because no further search is required if you have already found a dictionary.

```
bool is = NO;
for(NSDictionary *dic in array){
   if([dic objecetForKey:@"key"] != nil){
      is = YES;
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: typo in objectForKey (objecetForKey)

Answer (score 9):

KVC would look nice

```
NSArray *keys = [array valueForKeyPath:@"key"];
if([keys containsObject:@"myvalue"]) {
     NSLog(@"nice");
}
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't this follow the same process as the OP is already using? (admittedly with slightly shorter code). In fact, wouldn't this be *slower* because it's generating a new array of all elements whether it needs them or not.

Comment: @Dave yes -- but legibility beats performance 99% of the time ;) and the time it takes to create an array I save by not having to do the assign to the dict pointer ;) (it is 0.000000001 ns or so)

Comment: Awesome method. keyPath value is actually the KEY of the dictionary you're basing the equality of two objects (Ex. @"id", @"name").

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

Using **NSPredicates**

```
NSPredicate *applePred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                      @"employer.name == 'Apple'"];
NSArray *appleEmployees = [people filteredArrayUsingPredicate:applePred];
```

or **Using Blocks**

```
- (BOOL)personExists:(NSString *)key withValue:(NSString *)value {

  NSPredicate *predExists = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                         @"%K MATCHES[c] %@", key, value];
  NSUInteger index = [self.people indexOfObjectPassingTest:
                     ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                       return [predExists evaluateWithObject:obj];
                     }];

  if (index == NSNotFound) {
    return NO;
  }

  return YES;
}

[myArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [obj someTestForValue: value];
  }];
```

tutorial: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/10/19/searching-arrays-with-nspredicate-and-blocks.html